# Boot initialization problem, boot unknown partition, dual boot pc

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, boot-repair

It has been 3 days I'm trying to solve the boot problem. I have two systems, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 in different partitions.

I have tried many solutions:

1. I used Boot-Repair but it didn't work. Simply it tells me I need to create a boot partition.
2. I used GAG to try find out operating systems, but nothing, neither the recover of GRUB 2.
3. I tried reinstall windows 10 with installer CD, but it tells me I need choose the operating system.
4. I tried reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 but any options goes ahead, the continue button stays disable.

So, I'm trying to solve that with command line, and I'm using Ubuntu in TRY mode. I ran the Gparted and I had a big surprise, look:

[Unknown partitions and unmounted partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozBKj.png)

I don't know what to do to solve that, I am a beginner in Linux. I choose Ubuntu because I need to program in Ruby on Rails. But something screwed up all the initialization.

If you have some suggestions I can do, command lines, tutorials, everything will be helpful.

Comment: Can you please include a link to the diagnostic log file generated by Boot-Repair?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem following the steps:

1- I tried to install Ubuntu again a few more times, then the installation proceeded and created the grub again.
2- I ran the Boot-repair again, and using gparted I could see the boot partition.(as required by Boot-repair).
3- So, I uninstalled the Ubuntu using the OS-Uninstaller from Boot-repair.
4- I ran Windows installer, deleted all partitions preservating my data partitions;
5- Finally, Windows could be installed.

Observation:
If you have problems installing Windows run Boot-repair again, and try install Windows again.

I didn't install Ubuntu again, I will put it in other computer exchanging Windows by Ubuntu.(Only one operating system avoid this type of problems)